# Composition of squeeze operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, lie-algebra, second-quantization

I'm wondering if it exists a composition law for the squeezing operation ? I guess so for geometric reason, since they are (generalized, and the phase is annoying of course) hyperbolic rotations of the annihilation $a$ and creation $a^{\dagger}$ operators of some bosonic modes.

I define the squeezing operator as $$ S\left(\zeta\right) = e^{\Sigma} \;\; ; \;\; \Sigma = \frac{\zeta^{\ast} aa -\zeta a^{\dagger}a^{\dagger}}{2}$$
for any complex parameter $\zeta$.

**I would like to know the rule for $S\left(\zeta_{1}\right)\cdot S\left(\zeta_{2}\right)$ ?**

For instance, we know that 
$$D\left(\alpha\right)\cdot D\left(\beta\right)=D\left(\alpha + \beta\right) e^{\left(\alpha \beta^{\ast}-\beta\alpha^{\ast} \right)/2}$$
for the coherent / displacement operator $D\left(\alpha\right)=e^{\Delta}$ with $\Delta = \alpha^{\ast} a - \alpha a^{\dagger}$.

A reference for $S\left(\zeta_{1}\right)\cdot S\left(\zeta_{2}\right)$ would be sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I) OP is asking for the composition formula for so-called [*single mode squeezing operators*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_operator), see eq. (8) below. We will not here prove the composition formula (8), but only give partial hints and references.

The key is to realize that one can identify

$$  \sigma_{+}~:=~-\frac{1}{2} a^{\dagger}a^{\dagger}, \qquad \sigma_{-}~:=~\frac{1}{2} aa, \qquad\sigma_{3}~:=~a^{\dagger}a+\frac{1}{2} ,\tag{1} $$

with generators of a $su(1,1)\cong so(2,1; \mathbb{R})\cong sl(2,\mathbb{R})$ Lie algebra

$$  [\sigma_{+},\sigma_{-}]~=~\sigma_{3} , \qquad [\sigma_{3},\sigma_{\pm}]~=~\pm2 \sigma_{\pm}. \tag{2}$$

Here the single mode creation and annihilation operators satisfy

$$ [a,a^{\dagger}]~=~1.\tag{3}$$

The squeezing operator

$$  S(z)~:=~\exp\Sigma(z),\qquad
\Sigma(z)~:=~z\sigma_{+} + z^{\ast} \sigma_{-}, \qquad z~\in~ \mathbb{C},\tag{4}$$

may be written in normal-ordered form

$$S(z)~=~\exp\left(t\sigma_{+}\right)\exp\left(\ln(1-|t|^2)\frac{\sigma_{3}}{2}\right)\exp\left(t^{\ast}\sigma_{-}\right),\tag{5}$$

cf. e.g. Ref. 1 eq. (1.207), or Ref. 2 eqs. (2.16) and (3.4). Here

$$  z~=~re^{i\theta}~\in~ \mathbb{C}, \qquad r~\geq~ 0, \qquad\theta~\in~ \mathbb{R},\tag{6}$$

and

$$   t~:=~e^{i\theta}\tanh(r)~\in~ \mathbb{C}.\tag{7}$$

The composition formula reads

$$\begin{align} S(z_1) S(z_2)~=~&S(z_3)\exp\left( \ln\frac{1+t_1 t_2^{\ast}}{1+t_1^{\ast}t_2} \frac{\sigma_{3}}{2}\right), \cr t_3~:=~&\frac{t_1+t_2}{1+t_1^{\ast}t_2},  \end{align}\tag{8}$$

cf. e.g. Ref. 2 Exercise 3.8.

II) The squeezing operators (4) may be viewed as elements of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. We may use the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map#Lie_theory)

$$\tag{9}\exp: sl(2,\mathbb{C}) ~\longrightarrow~ SL(2,\mathbb{C}) $$

to generalized to operators of the form

$$\begin{align} X(\vec{\alpha}) ~:=~&\exp\left(  \vec{\alpha} \cdot \vec{\sigma} \right)~=~\exp\left( \alpha^{+} \sigma_{+}+\alpha^{3} \sigma_{3}+ \alpha^{-} \sigma_{-}\right),\cr
\vec{\alpha}~=~&(\alpha^{+},\alpha^{3}, \alpha^{-})\in \mathbb{C}^3. \end{align}\tag{10}$$

The composition formula (8) generalizes to the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff (BCH) formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)

$$ \vec{\gamma}~=~ \vec{f}(\vec{\alpha},\vec{\beta}), \tag{11} $$

where

$$ X(\vec{\alpha})  X(\vec{\beta}) ~=~X(\vec{\gamma}). \tag{12}$$

[See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29100/2451) Phys.SE post for the corresponding BCH formula for $SU(2)$ and $SO(3;\mathbb{R})$.] Note however that the exponential map (9) is *not* surjective

$${\rm Im}(\exp)
~=~\left\{M\in SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \mid {\rm Tr}(M)\neq -2\right\} ~\cup~ \left\{-{\bf 1}\right\} \subsetneq SL(2,\mathbb{C}), \tag{13}$$

which means that the BCH map (12) has singularities.

References:

1. P. Kok and B.W. Lovett, *Introduction to Optical Quantum Information Processing,* 2010.
2. G.S. Agarwal, *Quantum Optics,*  2012. [Note that Ref. 2 has the opposite sign convention $z\to -z$ in eq. (4), see Ref. 2. eqs. (2.14) and (3.2).]
3. D.R. Truax, *Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff relations and unitarity of $SU(2)$ and $SU(1,1)$ squeeze operators,* [Phys. Rev. D31 (1985) 1988](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.31.1988).
4. R.A. Fisher, M.M. Nieto, and V.D. Sandberg, *Impossibility of naively generalizing squeezed coherent states,* [Phys. Rev. D29 (1984) 1107](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.1107); section III. (Hat tip: [Cosmas Zachos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/66086/cosmas-zachos).)

Comment: Notes for later: $\quad\Sigma(z) \sim\begin{pmatrix}0&z\cr z^{\ast}&0\end{pmatrix}$; $\quad\Sigma(z)^2\sim r^2$; $\quad S(z) =\exp\Sigma(z) =\cosh\Sigma(z) +\sinh\Sigma(z)$ $\sim\cosh(r) +{\rm sinhc}(r)~\Sigma(z) =\cosh(r) +\sinh(r)~\Sigma(e^{i\theta})=\begin{pmatrix}c&s\cr s^{\ast}&c\end{pmatrix}$; $\quad\exp\left(t\sigma_{+}\right)\sim 1+t\sigma_{+}$; $\quad\exp\left(\nu\sigma_{3}\right) \sim \cosh(\nu)+\sinh(\nu)~\sigma_{3}=\begin{pmatrix}e^{\nu}&0\cr 0&e^{-\nu}\end{pmatrix}$; $\quad\exp\left(t^{\ast}\sigma_{-}\right) \sim 1+t^{\ast}\sigma_{-}$;

Comment: $\quad\exp\left(t\sigma_{+}\right) \exp\left(\nu \sigma_{3}\right)\exp\left(t^{\ast}\sigma_{-}\right)$ $\sim e^{-\nu}\left(t\sigma_{+} +t^{\ast}\sigma_{-} +|t|^2\begin{pmatrix}1&0\cr 0&0\end{pmatrix}\right)+\exp\left(\nu \sigma_{3}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{\nu}+|t|^2e^{-\nu}&te^{-\nu}\cr t^{\ast}e^{-\nu}& e^{-\nu}\end{pmatrix}$; $\quad 1-|t|^2 =e^{2\nu} =1/\cosh^2r$;

Comment: $\quad \exp\begin{pmatrix}a&b\cr c&-a\end{pmatrix}=\cosh d +\begin{pmatrix}a&b\cr c&-a\end{pmatrix} {\rm sinhc}d$; $\quad d:=\sqrt{a^2+bc}$; $\quad e^{-\nu}=\cosh d -a{\rm sinhc}d$; $\quad S(z_1)S(z_2)\sim \begin{pmatrix}c_1&s_1\cr s_1^{\ast}&c_1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_2&s_2\cr s_2^{\ast}&c_2\end{pmatrix}$; $\quad S(z_1)\exp\left(\nu\sigma_{3}\right) \sim \begin{pmatrix}c_3&s_3\cr s_3^{\ast}&c_3\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}e^{\nu}&0\cr 0&e^{-\nu}\end{pmatrix}$; Leads to 4 eqs.

Comment: $\quad X(\vec{\alpha}) := \exp\left(\vec{\alpha}\cdot\vec{\sigma} \right)$; $\quad \vec{\alpha} \cdot \vec{\sigma} = \alpha^{+} \sigma_{+}+\alpha^{3} \sigma_{3}+ \alpha^{-} \sigma_{-}$; $\quad \sigma_{\pm} = \frac{\sigma_{1} \pm i \sigma_{2}}{2}$; $\quad \alpha^{\pm} = \alpha^{1} \mp i \alpha^{2}$; $\quad g_{ij} = {\rm tr}(\sigma_{i}\sigma_{j})$; $\quad \sigma_{i}\sigma_{j} = g_{ij}{\bf 1}_{2\times 2} + i\epsilon_{ijk}g^{k\ell}\sigma_{\ell}$; $\quad \epsilon_{ijk}=\sqrt{|g|}[i,j,k]$;

Comment: $\quad\exp\left(\alpha^{3}\sigma_{3}\right) f\left(\alpha^{\pm} \sigma_{\pm}\right) \exp\left(-\alpha^{3}\sigma_{3}\right) =f\left(e^{\pm2\alpha^{3}} \alpha^{\pm} \sigma_{\pm}\right)$; $\quad\exp\left(\alpha^{\pm}\sigma_{\pm}+\alpha^{3}\sigma_{3}\right) = \exp\left(E(\pm2\alpha^{3})\alpha^{\pm}  \sigma_{\pm}\right)\exp\left(\alpha^{3}\sigma_{3}\right) $; $\quad\exp\left(\alpha^{\pm} \sigma_{\pm}\right)\exp\left(\alpha^{3}\sigma_{3}\right) =\exp\left(B(\pm2\alpha^{3})\alpha^{\pm} \sigma_{\pm}+\alpha^{3}\sigma_{3}\right)$;

Answer (score 0):

You will not have easily a closed general formula, because, first, the commutator of $aa$ and $a^+a^+$, so $4(a^+a + 1/2)$ does not commute with $aa$ and $a^+a^+$, and secondly,worse,  because the same thing happens for all the high-order commutators of the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)
(see more precisely Chapter "Zassenhaus formula")

It works with the $D\left(\alpha\right)$ because the commutator of $a$ and $a^+$ is $1$, so of course you have $[a, 1] = [a^+, 1] = 0$, and the infinite series of terms begin a short finite list (with $X \sim~ a, Y ~ \sim a^+$ ): 
$$e^X e^Y =  e^{X + Y}e^{\frac{1}{2}[X,Y]}$$

Maybe, you could calculate first the value of your operator in the ground state, that is :

$$ <0|S\left(\zeta_{1}\right)\cdot S\left(\zeta_{2}\right)|0>$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's precisely because I'm not interested in the ground state expectation value that I was asking this question. Even acting on the ground state, the squeeze state has no tabulated expression: it's just a sum of the even power of the expansion of the exponential argument as far as I know. Thanks again.