# Normal ordering of an exponential

Tags: operators, commutator, lie-algebra, coherent-states, squeezed-states

I would like to recalculate Eq.(2.4) in [PRA, 31,4,(1985)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.31.2721), which expresses the exponential of operators as a normal ordering form. This equation reads

\begin{equation}
D=e^{\alpha K_{+} - \alpha^{*} K_{-}} = e^{\xi K_{+}} e^{\gamma K_{0}} e^{- \xi^{*} K_{-}},
\end{equation}

where $\alpha =-\tau e^{-i \phi}/2$, $\gamma= \ln (1-|\xi|^2)$ and $\xi = - \tanh(\tau/2) e^{-i \phi}$. Here $K_{0}, K_{+}, K_{-}$ are the generators of a SU(1,1) Lie group which satisfy
$[K_{0}, K_{\pm}] = \pm  K_{\pm}$ and $[K_{-},K_{+}]=2 K_{0}$.

In my initial attempt, I used the [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) to derive the above relation. My calculations read

\begin{equation}
e^{\alpha K_{+} - \alpha^{*} K_{-}}  = 
e^{\alpha K_{+}} e^{-\alpha^{*} K_{-}} 
e^{-|\alpha|^{2} K_{0}}
e^{[- \alpha^{*} |\alpha|^2 K_{+}  + \alpha |\alpha|^2 K_{-}]/6}  e^{-|\alpha|^4 K_{0}/2} + \ldots.
\end{equation}

But I couldn't derive the expressions for $\gamma, \xi$ given in the paper so far. Could you spot the possible typo that I've made?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67371/2451

Comment: Avoid pre-packaged formulas! Use the trick of section III of [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.1107), earlier that year!.

Comment: @CosmasZachos +1 This reference is great! Thank you very much!