# What is the difference between commutator of exponential with an operator and the Hadamard's formula?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator, squeezed-states

I need to compute this:

$$ [ e^{-\sigma K_+}, K_{-} ] $$  and $K_{\pm} $ has the following commutator relations

$$ [K_0, K_{\pm} ] = \pm K_{\pm}$$

$$ [K_{-}, K_{+} ] =  2K_0 .$$

I tried to expand the exponential operator and compute the interated commutator

$$ [ e^{-\sigma K_+}, K_{-} ]  = \sum_0^\infty \frac{(-\sigma)^n}{n!} [K_{+}^n, K_{-}  ] = 2 \sigma K_0 - 2 \sigma^2 K_{-} $$

This result gives zero, but if we expand the sum, we see that only surviving the two first terms.

My question is when can you use this formula? :

[image]

and this is different from this:

[image]

I take BCH relations  from wiki.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_transformation_(quantum_mechanics)

I really appreciate your help, my final goal is to calculate this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Recall first that the [adjoint representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) is given  as $$({\rm ad} X)Y~:=~[X,Y].\tag{1}$$
2. We can then write nested commutators as $$({\rm ad} X)^nY.\tag{2}$$
3. [Hadamard's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646480/2451) [formula](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hadamard%27s+formula) can then be stated as
   $$ e^XYe^{-X}~=~e^{{\rm ad} X}Y. \tag{3}$$
4. OP and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_transformation_(quantum_mechanics)#Relation_to_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) instead adapt the notation
   $$ [(X)^n, Y]\tag{4}$$
   for the nested commutators (2), which is confusing, since (2) is *not* the same as
   $$X^n  Y -Y X^n ,\tag{5}$$
   if $n>1$. Presumably the core of OP's questions is caused by the use of the confusing notation (4).
5. For OP's squeezed state formula at the end, my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67392/2451) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of the BCH identity and the Hadamard Lemma ((3) of the answer of @Qmechanic, above) you are quoting is that commutators make most sense for elements of the Lie algebra, which your mixed commutator of a group and algebra element  is evidently *not*.

So your first task it to clean it up into a product of two such:
$$ [ e^{-\sigma K_+}, K_{-} ]= ( e^{-\sigma K_+} K_{-} e^{\sigma K_+}-  K_{-} ) ~~~e^{-\sigma K_+}. $$
Now, as per your [Hadamard Lemma of WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), this is a product of the *algebra element* in the parenthesis, times the *group element* (the exponential).

Section III of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.1107) reminds you of the basic technique involving faithful representations of Lie algebras (not groups!), such as the Pauli-matrix doublet; an algebra identity holding for such a representation, holds for the abstract algebra *in general*: the combinatorics of the CBH expansion only involves commutators in the exponent, and is therefore identical for ***all irreps***!

As a consequence, the algebra factor of your  expression $( e^{-\sigma K_+} K_{-} e^{\sigma K_+}-  K_{-} ) $ is trivial to evaluate with the doublet rep, *κ*,
$$
\kappa_+= i\begin{pmatrix}0 &1\\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}, ~~ \kappa_-=   \kappa_+^T, ~~ \kappa_0= {1\over 2} \begin{pmatrix}1 &0\\ 0&-1 \end{pmatrix},
$$
since, explicitly, these matrices yield
$$
 e^{-\sigma \kappa_+} \kappa_{-} e^{\sigma \kappa_+}-  \kappa_{-} =2\sigma \kappa_0+ \sigma^2 \kappa_+ ~~~\leadsto \\
 e^{-\sigma K_+} K_{-} e^{\sigma K_+}-  K_{-}= 2\sigma  K_0+ \sigma^2  K_+ . 
$$

You may proceed with parsing out and evaluating more complicated expressions. Remember, the representations are only faithful for Lie algebra equations/identities, but *not* universal  enveloping algebra such: You crucially *need* to know the expression evaluated above (in parenthesis) is in the Lie algebra! This does not obtain for the entire expression involving the group element.