# How is $j=1/2$ representation, $U(R(\theta,\hat{\bf n}))=e^{i{\sigma}\cdot{\hat {\bf n}}\theta/2}$, is a projective representation of ${\rm SO}(3)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, rotation, spinors

A projective unitary representation of ${\rm SO(3)}$ satisfies $$U(R_1)U(R_2)=e^{i\phi(R_1,R_2)}U(R_1R_2)\tag{1}$$ where $R_1,R_2\in {\rm SO(3)}$. How to show that the $j=1/2$ representation, $U(R(\theta,\hat{\bf n}))=e^{i{\sigma}\cdot{\hat {\bf n}}\theta/2}$, is a projective representation of ${\rm SO}(3)$ i.e., satisfies the condition $(1)$. To do this, one has to show that for $$R_1R_2=R_3\Rightarrow U(R_1)U(R_2)=e^{i\phi}U(R_3).\tag{3}$$ Any suggestions how to show this or at least check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. OP describes [projective representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation) in terms of a 2-cocycle, see section 3 below. An alternative description is in terms of a quotient $$PSU(2)~:=~ SU(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2~\cong~SO(3),\tag{A}$$
   where $SU(2)$ denotes the 2-dimension $j=1/2$ non-projective defining/fundamental/spinor representation and
   $$\mathbb{Z}_{2}~\cong~\{\pm {\bf 1}_{2 \times 2}\}.\tag{B}$$
   In other words, in this latter description the 2-dimensional representation of $SO(3)$ is [double-valued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function), i.e. there are 2 branches $\pm U$ represents the same $SO(3)$ rotation.
2. Let $\vec{\alpha}=\theta\hat{\bf n}$ be a rotation-vector in the [axis-angle representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) $(\hat{\bf n},\theta)$. The opposite branch is given by the axis-angle representation $(-\hat{\bf n},2\pi\!-\!\theta)$. To describe a general $SO(3)$-element ($SU(2)$-element) it is enough to consider a rotation-vector $\vec{\alpha}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ with length $|\vec{\alpha}|\leq \pi$ ($|\vec{\alpha}|\leq 2\pi$), respectively. Note that the $4\pi$-periodicity of $SU(2)$ becomes the familiar  $2\pi$-periodicity of $SO(3)$. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/394152/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174562/2451) related Phys.SE posts.
3. From the non-projective defining representation of $SU(2)$, we have
   $$U(\vec{\gamma})~=~U(\vec{\alpha})U(\vec{\beta}) ,\tag{C}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29100/2451) Phys.SE post. As mentioned before, we may assume that $|\vec{\alpha}|,|\vec{\beta}|,|\vec{\gamma}| \leq 2\pi$. However, if we only want to use rotation-vectors with lengths $\leq \pi$ (corresponding to $SO(3)$-rotations), we might have to use the opposite branch. Such a transition costs a non-trivial 2-cofactor in eq. (C).

References:

1. G 't Hooft, [*Introduction to Lie Groups in Physics*](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Ehooft101/lectures/lieg.html), lecture notes; chapters 3 + 6. The pdf file is available [here](http://www.phys.uu.nl/%7Ethooft/lectures/lieg07.pdf).

Comment: The definition I used is the one given in Weinberg's QFT. But with this definition, I have a difficulty seeing which $U$ matrix satisfies a relation of the form $U(R_1)U(R_2)=e^{i\phi}U(R_1 R_2)$. Maybe I am confused by the notation, here. @Qmechanic

Comment: Yes, Weinberg uses a 2-cocycle.

Comment: Can you please tell how the notation $U(R_1)U(R_2)=e^{i\phi}U(R_1R_2)$ makes sense? For which $U$ matrices this relation is true? @Qmechanic

Comment: @SRS You cannot find *SU(2) matrices* for which this holds, else it would not be representation of SU(2).

Comment: You are probably right. But I am confused by the notation of Weinberg : $U(R_1)U(R_2)=e^{i\phi(R_1,R_2)}U(R_1R_2)$. What is $U$ here? @ZeroTheHero

Answer (score 1):

Take $\hat{\bf{n}}_1=\hat{\bf{n}}_2$, and $\theta_1+\theta_2=2\pi$.  As an $SO(3)$ element, you should have $U(R_1)U(R_2)=U(2\pi)=1$ but here you get $-1$.

Thus, you get $U(R_1)U(R_2)=e^{i\phi}1$, where $e^{i\phi}=-1$ (or $\phi=\pi$)

Comment: Where is the phase $e^{i\phi}$? We should get $U(R_1)U(R_2)=e^{i\phi}U(R_1R_2)$. Right?

Comment: just added a bit to answer your question.

Comment: You took $R_1=R(\theta_1,\hat{\bf n}_1)$ and $R_2=R(\theta_2,\hat{\bf n}_2)$. With $\hat{\bf n}_1=\hat{\bf n}_2=\hat{\bf n}$, and $\theta_1=2\pi-\theta_2=\theta$, 
$$R_1R_2=R(\hat{\bf n},\theta)R(\hat{\bf n},2\pi-\theta)=R(\hat{\bf n},2\pi)=1.$$ Now, $$U(R_1)U(R_2)=e^{i{\sigma}\cdot{\hat {\bf n}}\theta/2}e^{i{\sigma}\cdot{\hat {\bf n}}(2\pi-\theta)/2}=e^{i{\sigma}\cdot{\hat {\bf n}}\pi}=-1$$ and $$U(R_3)=U(R(\hat{\bf n},2\pi))=e^{i{\sigma}\cdot{\hat {\bf n}}\pi}=-1$$ which says $U(R_1)U(R_2)=U(R_3)$. So I dot yet get this.  Any error? @ZeroTheHero

Comment: Any comment? @ZeroTheHero

Comment: As elements of SO(3), $R(\theta_1)R(\theta_2)=R(2\pi)=1$,  Here, you have (as elements of SU(2)) $R(\theta_1)R(\theta_2)=(-1)R(2\pi)=-1$.  Thus, as elements of SU2, the product is "almost" the same as the product of SO(3) elements  provided you allow multiplication by a phase.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm afraid I don't get it. If I try to express in the form of Eq.$(1)$, all I find that $U(\theta)U(2\pi-\theta)=e^{i\phi}(-1)=e^{i\phi}U(2\pi)$ with $\phi=0$.

Comment: Of course in SU(2) the product is just $U(R_1)U(R_2)=U(R_1R_2)$ else it would not be a representation of SU(2). It is when you make an interpretation of this product *as product of SO(3) elements*  that the phase appears (in the sense that $\theta$ labels an element in SO(3)).  That's why you have a projective representation of SO(3) (not of SU(2)).  There are no irreducible representations of SO(3) of dimension 2 so it cannot be that $e^{-i\theta\sigma_z/2}$ is in SO(3), yet the SU(2) elements combine "almost" as SO(3) elements.