# Are Pauli matrices invariant tensors in the representation of $\frac12 \otimes \frac12 \otimes 1$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, spinors, invariants

If we raise the index of the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) with [Levi-Civita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#(Anti-)Commutation_relations) symbol $\epsilon$ we obtain the 2-index [spinors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor) $(\sigma_i)^{AB} = (\sigma_i)^A{}_C \ \epsilon^{CB}$. The textbook (Ref. 1) argued that they are [invariant tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariants_of_tensors) in the representation $\frac12 \otimes \frac12 \otimes 1$. However, I raised the index by $\epsilon$, which gives that:
$$
(\sigma_1)^{AB}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\quad
(\sigma_2)^{AB}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 i & 0 \\
 0 & i \\
\end{array}
\right),\quad
(\sigma_3)^{AB}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
How can I verify they are invariant under the representation $\frac12 \otimes \frac12 \otimes 1$?

Reference:

1. Carlo Rovelli and Francesca Vidotto, *Covariant Loop Quantum Gravity*, Exercise 1.9 pp. 27. ISBN:9781107069626.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Pauli matrices are invariant in the sense that
$$\sum_{j=1}^3 U \sigma_j U^{-1}(R^{-1})^j{}_k~=~ \sigma_k ,\tag{A} $$
where $U\in SU(2)$ is a $2\times 2$-matrix in the spin-$1/2$ representation and $R\in SO(3)$ is the corresponding $3\times 3$-matrix  in the spin-$1$ representation, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/640384/2451).